# 74185 IC (binary to BCD converter) don't work in Proteus

Tags: proteus

I try to design circuit that convert 10 bit binary to BCD with 74185 IC in Proteus, but when i run this project output of this IC like this attached picture is unknown(IC don't work! and i didn't receive any error!) and I did active enable. why? and how can give suitable output?[image: in this attached image i test enable with a logicProbe and change it but still IC don't work.]

[image]

In this attached image i try to convert 5 bit binary to BCD and i test enable input with a LOGICPROBE and change it, but still IC don't work.

**EDIT**
like this link i use from resistor network and all output were 1.
[Weird ULN2003 to 7-segment behaviour in Proteus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98963/weird-uln2003-to-7-segment-behaviour-in-proteus)
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the device when you search for it in the parts list? It may be that it doesn't have a SPICE model, hence having undefined outputs, and using pullup resistors will make them all high.

Answer (score 1):

Outputs of 74185 are open collector.

Comment: thanks, and can you say that how to fix it?

Comment: @James Please consider adding more information so OP can modify his circuit accordingly? Your one liner is helpful, but with more context it could help OP.

Comment: @Reyhane, google `open collector outputs`

Comment: I have updated this question.